# CSV won't import by key in hash (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm having problems importing this CSV:

```
municipality,province,province abbrev,country,region
Vancouver,British Columbia,BC,Canada,Metro Vancouver - North
```

Specifically, `Vancouver` is not being returned when I look for its value by its key:

`municipality_name = row["municipality"]`

Here's the code:

```
def self.import_csv(file)
  CSV.foreach(file, headers: true,
                    skip_blanks: true,
                    skip_lines: /^(?:,\s*)+$/,
                    col_sep: ",") do |row|

    municipality_name = row["municipality"]
    puts row.to_h
    puts "municipality_name: #{municipality_name}"
    puts "row[0]: #{row[0]}"
  end
end
```

Here's the output:

```
irb(main):052:0> Importers::Municipalities.import_csv('tmp/municipalities.csv')
{"municipality"=>"Vancouver", "province"=>"British Columbia", "province abbrev"=>"BC", "country"=>"Canada", "region"=>"Metro Vancouver - North"}
municipality_name:
row['municipality']:
row[0]: Vancouver
```

Seems like I'm missing something obvious.  I thought maybe there was a hidden character in the CSV but turned on hidden characters in Sublime and no dice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `to_h` on the row if you want to access it by its keys. Otherwise, it is an array-like object, accessible by indices.

```
def self.import_csv(file)
  CSV.foreach(file, headers: true,
                    skip_blanks: true,
                    skip_lines: /^(?:,\s*)+$/,
                    col_sep: ",") do |row|
    row = row.to_h
    municipality_name = row["municipality"]
    puts "municipality_name: #{municipality_name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think this is true.  I can access the other columns by header name without calling .to_h on the row.  e.g. province_name = row["province"] returns the value for the second column.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Having `headers: true` should allow you to do this without having to call `to_h`. Using your exact code on my computer and seems to work. Have you tried a different CSV file?

Comment: Yep just used the same content in a new file and it worked.  Maybe an encoding issue?  I'm going to mark this an answered.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah I've had issues with CSV encoding as well. You're welcome anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was a problem with the CSV and the code works fine.  Created a new CSV, typed in the same content, and it worked.  Maybe an invisible character that Sublime wasn't showing?  Can't verify as I wiped the original CSV that was causing issues.